# C# extract single characters from a 'string'

Tags: c#, arrays

C# newbie...(again)
Slowly getting used to String class (and everything else!)
Wondering how to manipulate chars like a char[] array

My code below -

```
    private void sendString(String stringToSend)
    {
        for(int p=0; p < stringToSend.Length; p++)
        {
            // I want to select individual characters from stringToSend
            Console.Write(stringToSend);  **<< XX HERE ? XX**
            // followed by an inter-character delay
        }
    }
```

Of course, this works for the *whole* string. but I only want to send one charater at a time with a delay between chars.
TIA

Comment: Just to be clear, you cannot *manipulate* individual chars in a string. In C#, strings are **immutable**, meaning that they cannot be changed after created. You can retrieve the individual chars using indexers (array notation), but you will need to convert the string to a char array if you want to manipulate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the string's [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx) to access its individual characters, like this:

```
private void sendString(String stringToSend)
{
    for(int p=0; p < stringToSend.Length; p++)
    {
        Console.Write(stringToSend[p]);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: They just call `toString` like this `ComPort.Write(stringToSend[p].toString())` @MC

Comment: Magic - thanks!
C++ had all those meaningless colons, C# replaced them with meaningful () pairs!

Answer (score 1):

First solution is to use of **indexer**

```
 private void sendString(String stringToSend)
{
    for(int p=0; p < stringToSend.Length; p++)
    {
        Console.Write(stringToSend[p]);
        //delay code syntax here

    }
}
```

And second solution is to use ToCharArray function to convert string to character array.

```
    private void sendString(String stringToSend)
{
    char[] sendchar = stringToSend.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char item in sendchar)
            {
                Console.Write(item);
                //delay here
            }
}
```

But it's better to use first solution.Because that will simply iterate over string and using `ToCharArray()`will allocate new memory(Extra).

Comment: The `ToCharArray` is redundant. You can just as easily use a `foreach` on the string itself.

Comment: Yes using ToCharArray() is a bit overhead also.